# Continuously updated database shared between multiple AWS EC2 instances

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

For a small personal project, I've been scraping some data every 5 minutes and saving it in a SQL database. So far I've been using a tiny EC2 AWS instance in combination with a 100GB EBS storage. This has been working great for the scraping, but is becoming unusable for analysing the resulting data, as the EC2 instance doesn't have enough memory.

The data analysis only happens irregularly, so it would feel a waste to pay 24/7 to have a bigger EC2 instance, so I'm looking for something more flexible. From reading around I've learned:

- You can't connect EBS to two EC2 instances at the same time, so spinning up a second temporary big instance whenever analysis needed isn't an option.
- AWS EFS seems a solution, but is quite a lot more expensive and considering my limited knowledge, I'm not a 100% sure this is the ideal solution.
- The serverless options like Amazon Athena look great, but this is based on S3 which is a no-go for data that needs continuous updating (?).

I assume this is quite a common usecase for AWS, so I'm hoping to try to get some pointers in the right direction. Are there options I'm overlooking that fit my problem? Is EFS the right way to go?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use RDS and a Read Replica

Comment: I'm confused about where your bottleneck lies -- is it the SQL database, or your main application on EC2? Is your database on the EC2 instance too, or are you using Amazon RDS? Feel free to edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input! I'll edit my initial question, but: The database is on the EC2 instance (with EBS storage). The bottle neck is RAM memory on the EC2 instance (only 1GB), which doesn't allow me to query the database efficiently.

Comment: @Claudiordgz Because I didn't know the Read Replica concept, I'll look into it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers by previous users are great. Let's break them down in options. It sounds to me that your initial stack is a Custom SQL Database you installed in EC2.

#### Option 1 - RDS Read Replicas

Move your DB to RDS, this would give you a lot of goodies, but the main one we are looking for is Read Replicas if your reading/s grows you can create additional read replicas and put them behind a load balancer. This setup is the lowest hanging fruit without too many code changes.

#### Option 2 - EFS to Share Data between EC2 Instances

Using EFS is not straightforward, to no fault of EFS. Some databases save unique IDs to the filesystem, meaning you can't share the hard drive.  EFS is a service and will add some lag to every read/write operation. Depending on how your installed Database distribution it might not even be possible.

#### Option 3 - Athena and S3

Having the workers save to S3 instead of SQL is also doable, but it means rewriting your web scraping tool. You can call S3 -> PutObject on the same key multiple times, and it will overwrite the previous object. Then you would need to rewrite your analytics tool to query S3. This option is excellent, and it's likely the cheapest in 'operation cost,' but it means that you have to be acquainted with S3, and more importantly, Athena. You would also need to figure out how you will save new data and the best file format for your application. You can start with regular JSON or CSV blobs and then later move to Apache Parquet for lower cost. (For more info on how that statement means savings see here: https://aws.amazon.com/athena/pricing/)

#### Option 4 - RedShift

RedShift is for BigData, I would wait until querying regular SQL is a problem (multiple seconds per query), and then I would start looking into it. Sure it would allow you query very for cheap, but you would probably have to set up a Pipeline that listens to SQL (or is triggered by it) and then updates RedShift. Reason is because RedShift scales depending on your querying needs, and you can spin up multiple machines easily to make querying faster.

Comment: Thanks @Claudiordgz, much appreciated! Read around about option 1-3, including the parquet + S3 option (e.g. this great blog https://read.acloud.guru/how-we-built-a-big-data-analytics-platform-on-aws-for-100-large-users-for-under-2-a-month-b37425b6cc4 ), was told about option 4 here, but this kind of overview is extremely helpful to make an informed decision. Think I'll opt for the low hanging fruit first, unless I find the time to dive into Athena/S3.

Comment: Thank you for the blog post @Toekan!

Answer (score 1):

1. As far as I can see S3 and Athena is good option for this. I am not sure about your concern NOT to use S3, but once you can save scraped data in S3 and you can analyse them with Athena (Pay Per Query model).
2. Alternatively, you can use RedShift to save data and analyse which has on demand service similar to ec2 on demand pricing model.

Also, you may use Kenisis Firehose which can be used to analyse data real time as and when you ingest them.

Comment: From reading around it doesn't seem possible to update data on S3? So how would I add my newly scraped data every 5 minutes to the database? Or is there a way around this?

I'll have a look at Redshift too, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your **scraping workers should store data in Amazon S3.** That way, worker instances can be scaled (and even turned off) without having to worry about data storage. Keep process data (eg what has been scraped, where to scrape next) in a database such as DynamoDB.

When you need to query the data saved to Amazon S3, **Amazon Athena is ideal if it is stored in a readable format** (CSV, ORC, etc).

However, if you need to read unstructured data, your application can **access the files directly S3** by either downloading and using them, or reading them as streams. For this type of processing, you could launch a large EC2 instance with plenty of resources, then turn it off when not being used. Better yet, launch it as a **Spot instance** to save money. (It means your system will need to cope with potentially being stopped mid-way.)